# Controller is getting one image for both names

Tags: laravel, image, form-data

i'm sending the image with form data one image for student marksheet and one image for it's profile picture. but when i see the response in headers it showing one image for both the parameters.

HTML Code for marksheet

```
<div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="tei" class="tei">
  <label class="control-label">Image</label><i class="bar"></i>
</div>
```

HTML Code for profile picture

```
<div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" >
  <label class="control-label">Image</label><i class="bar"></i>
</div>
```

Jquery code for send image to controller

```
formdata.append('image',$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
formdata.append('tei',$("input[name='tei']")[0].files[0]);
```

Controller Code

```
public function studentform(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

Header Response

Here image is use for profile picture and tei for marksheet (now look both the names are getting same image name)

```
image" => UploadedFile {#264
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Capture.JPG"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
```

```
"tei" => UploadedFile {#265
    -test: false
    -originalName: "Capture.JPG"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Javascript code you are appending one image with the input `type` and the other with the input `name`, Try appending both with the input `name`.

Depending on your HTML structure (e.g. which element comes first), it will select the wrong image.

Try this:

```
formdata.append('image', $("input[name='image']")[0].files[0]);  
formdata.append('tei', $("input[name='tei']")[0].files[0]);
```